patents data spilling to next line using patentpy
I am using the following code. The values in the last column of the output spill to the next line. How to prevent it from happening so?
I have checked posts on python on csv export but unable to resolve this issue.
pip install patentpy

python -X utf8 

from patentpy.acquire import get_bulk_patent_data

get_bulk_patent_data(year = 2023, week =1,output_file="E:\\test.csv")


You can not control CSV by writing inside the "get_bulk_patent_data" function.
You are facing this issue is most probably due to the newline characters within the data being written to the CSV. It is known that "get_bulk_patent_data" handles files writing internally so you can not directly modify.
Here is the formatted solution:

    from patentpy.acquire import get_bulk_patent_data
    get_bulk_patent_data(year=2023, week=1, output_file="E:\\test.csv")


I hope this will resolve your query.
